# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: php, sql, oracle

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00917: missing comma in C:\xampp\htdocs\TTO\pulldata2.php on line 66

**Code**:

```
$sql = "INSERT into project (PROJECT_ID , PROJECT_NAME ,CREATED , LAST_MODIFIED , PSTART_DATE , PEND_DATE)VALUES(project_id_seq.nextval , '$projectname1' ,'$un' , 'to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')' ,'to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')','to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')') ";
$insert_project=oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_execute($insert_project);
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your calls to `to_date` in single quotes? Take those out and it should work fine, what you're currently doing is generating incorrect strings.

Answer (score 0):

Format your SQL because now it's hard to read

You can't put variable in '' because variables won't be parsed. Same affect functions' names.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `project` (`PROJECT_ID`, `PROJECT_NAME`, `CREATED`, `LAST_MODIFIED`, PSTART_DATE, PEND_DATE)
                      VALUES(project_id_seq.nextval, $projectname1, $un, to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) "; 
$insert_project=oci_parse($conn,$sql); 
oci_execute($insert_project);
```

Comment: m getting invalid character for this ,
what i am doing is ... taking two dates in format mm/dd/yyyy 
and passing them to oracle database

Answer (score 0):

- try this

  ```
   INSERT into project (PROJECT_ID , PROJECT_NAME ,CREATED ,
                   LAST_MODIFIED , PSTART_DATE , PEND_DATE)VALUES        
                   (project_id_seq.nextval , '$projectname1' ,'$un' , 
                    to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') ,
                    to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),
                    to_date('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'));
  ```